# mongoose post remove middleware is not getting called

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this route controller to delete an item:

```
exports.deleteShoppingItem = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
const shoppingItem = await ShoppingItem.findById(req.params.id);

if (!shoppingItem) {
    return next(
        new ErrorResponse(`shoppingItem not found on id ${req.params.id}`, 404)
);
}

//check if the current user is the owner of the shopping item
if (shoppingItem.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
return next(
  new ErrorResponse(
    `user with user is not allowed to update this shopping item`,
    401
  )
);
}
```

```
await shoppingItem.deleteOne();
```

and this is my middleware that I want to be executed whenever an item is deleted:

```
ShoppingItemSchema.post("remove", async function () {
  console.log("removing")
  await this.constructor.calculateTotalBoughtCost(this.user),
  await this.constructor.calculateTotalCost(this.user);
});
```

but this post remove is never getting called even though the items are being deleted successfully.

I tried to use `remove()`, but it says remove is not function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "deleteOne" methodName instead of "remove".

```
ShoppingItemSchema.post("deleteOne", async function () {
console.log("removing")
await this.constructor.calculateTotalBoughtCost(this.user),
await this.constructor.calculateTotalCost(this.user);
});
```

You can read the post() hook middlewares documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post)

Comment: oh nice Yes the middleware is called but now it is returning this error
TypeError: this.constructor.calculateTotalBoughtCost is not a function

Comment: You need to share the code where you have defined the schema and the function.